# Deliver Email Based on Field Selection on a Product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to deliver an Woocommerce New Order Email to a vendor based on which dropdown a customer selected on a product. Basically, a customer chooses an Agency, and based on which agency they select that agency receives a New Order email.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function new_order_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient; // (Optional)

    // Get the order ID (retro compatible)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    // Get the custom field value (with the right $order_id)
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'agency', true );

        if ($custom_field == "Citizens Inn"){
            $recipient .= ', citizensinn@gmail.com'; 
            return $recipient;
        }


        if ($custom_field == "NE Arc"){
            $recipient .= ', nearc@gmail.com';
            return $recipient;
        }

        if ($custom_field == "Lifebridge - Salem"){
            $recipient .= ', lifebridge@gmail.com';
            return $recipient;
        }

    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order','new_order_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

Unfortunately, it keeps delivering to only the first email citizensinn@gmail.com no matter which option is selected. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you check the metadata in order is saved? looks like `$recipient` returns the default setting you could swap your condition to check your `$custom_field` exist or not.

Comment: Isn't `get_post_meta` supposed to check if the `$custom_field` data is saved?

Comment: _"on which dropdown a customer selected on a product"_. If I understand correctly, these can be several (different) products in an order? 
So either you have to work on the basis of the product ID versus the order ID or either the post meta value is just wrong. You can solve these kinds of issues by debugging, and by looking what value there is for the meta stored in the database.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos Yes, you could leave the code on the order page and echo the $custom_field in anywhere to check.